# Should a multicast router punt the multicast packets in addition to routing those packets if the router has an interface in this multicast group?

Tags: multicast, pim

If the multicast router has the `(S,G)` route present and the same destination address `G` is also set on one of the router interfaces, then should the router send the packets addressed to group address `G` for local processing in addition to routing those packets?

For example, let's say that the router has a `(10.0.2.123,239.3.7.7)` route present and there is a router interface subscribed to `239.3.7.7`. Should the router (according to standards) punt the packets sourced from `10.0.2.123` and addressed to `239.3.7.7` besides forwarding those packets?